# how do you animate the plot of 3D complex function z^2+1 in blender

Tags: python, animation

I want to create a animation on the process of the 2D parabola function `z^2+1` becoming 3D function.
like this:

[image]

How to do it using python in Blender?

Comment: What do you mean by animation? Could you illustrate it?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way you can do it with geo nodes.

To create the graph of a function $f = f(x,y)$, you can create a grid mesh and offset each point $(x,y)$ to a height of $f(x,y)$. The group `FUNCTION` computes $f(x,y)$ in this example.

[image]

If you want to attach a color to the graph, you can compute the color from $(x,y)$ and store it as a color attribute on the mesh. A simple material is applied that displays the color. The group `COLOR` computes the color in this example.

[image]

Turning specifically to complex numbers now, X and Y would be the real and imaginary parts of the function argument $z$.

Now normally a complex graph would use $|f(z)|$ as the height and $\operatorname{Arg}(f(z))$ as the hue. But you can tell this isn't what's being plotted in your example.

AFAICT, in your example, the graph is the graph of $f(z)=\operatorname{Re}(z^2+1)$ and the hue appears to just be a linear function of $\operatorname{Im}(z)$? Then since

$$\operatorname{Re}(z^2+1) = x^2 - y^2 + 1$$

I would try something like this.

[image]

And since this is done with geonodes, you can animate it by animating a socket. For example you can change the domain of the graph by changing the sizes on the Grid node.

[image]